# How can safely I test a UPS that doesn't have a working battery?

Tags: ups

I have a UPS that's about 10 years old, and doesn't have it's battery. The thing will not turn on without the battery. Is there any way I can test it to see if it still works? Will connecting the `+` and `-` connectors of the battery inside do the job? I’m only trying to show the buyer it still works.

Comment: Seems the consensus so far is that it's not safe.  My gut instinct would be that it may be model-dependent: some might not require a battery, but others would.  So, even if someone says that it can be done safely, I wouldn't trust that unless the information was specific to the exact model of your UPS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, connecting the `+` and `-` together won’t work. In fact it will put a dead short across the UPS’s battery charger. If you’re lucky the UPS will detect this and *not* try to send charging current through the dead short. If you’re not lucky the charging circuit will be damaged.

You’ll either have to sell it as-is and untested, or else get a battery for it.

Edit - added:

Consider: Even if the UPS will pass AC power through without a battery connected (as some will), then what exactly would you be demonstrating that works? At that point it is just a line-interactive AC voltage regulator (assuming it has that function). You don't know if the battery charging circuit works, and you don't know if the inverter (battery to AC output) side works, and together those are pretty much everything in a UPS.